# Many large projects, routing for image server asp.NET mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, cdn

I work in a company that has over 70 asp.net mvc projects (very similar ones)

All images are linked like this : Url.Content("~/imagefoldername/picname.jpg");

Now I want to merge those 70 projects into one, very similar to Drupals multiple-site per installation system.

I'd like to have all images on one server (maybe with the possibility of even using a CDN)

I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow Route /imagefoldername/picname.jpg to something like

http://img.mycdnname.com/project1/picname.jpg

This way I don't need to iterate trough all views int the 70 projects, but just add a rule to global.asax, and would save me a lot of time.

Is it possible? How do I route it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**IIS URL Rewriting module**](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) or just setup separate route in MVC and create an action that will return HTTP 302.

Make sure that you read [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/02/redirecting-routes-to-maintain-persistent-urls.aspx) by **Phil Haack** first.